# Joomla module install.sql not executing

Tags: sql, joomla, joomla-module

I have the following file `install.sql` in my site module's `/sql` folder. And I'm referencing it from my module's `.xml` file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="2.5" client="site" method="install">
    <name>bbb Referral</name>
    <author>AAA Media</author>
    <creationDate>23/02/2012</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later</license>
    <authorEmail>info@AAA</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>AAA</authorUrl>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <description>bbb Referral</description>
    <files>
        <filename module="mod_bbb_referral">mod_bbb_referral.php</filename>
        <folder>tmpl</folder>
        <filename>index.html</filename>                       
        <filename>mod_bbb_referral.xml</filename>
    </files>
    <install folder="site">
        <sql>
            <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/install.sql</file>
        </sql>
    </install>
    <languages folder="language/en-GB">
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.ini</language>
    </languages>
    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">
                <field name="header_text" type="textarea" default="" label="Header text" description="Header text to show before friends list" />
                <field name="footer_text" type="textarea" default="" label="Footer text" description="Footer text to show below friends list" />
                <field name="body_text" type="textarea" default="" label="Body text"
                       description="Body text to include in referral" />
                <field name="thankyou_text" type="textarea" default="" label="Thank you text"
                       description="Thank you text to show when successful" />
                <field name="error_text" type="textarea" default="Error encountered. Please try again later." label="Error text"
                       description="Error text to show if share was not successful in any way." />
                <field name="socialgraph_url" type="text" default="" size="60" label="Social Graph request URL"
                       description="URL to access when getting user's friend list, leave {filter}, {skip} and {count} in URL, they will be replaced upon run-time." />
                <field name="socialgraph_filter" type="text" default="@Friends" label="Social Graph list filter"
                       description="Filter to use when getting list." />
                <field name="socialgraph_page_count" type="text" default="" label="Friends per page" description="Default is 26, leave empty to use default" />
                <field name="socialgraph_oauth_scope" type="text" default="graph/read" label="OAuth scope" description="Separated by a {space}. DO NOT CHANGE if you're unsure." />
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

But it specifically does not execute the create part of the table contained in `/sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__oauth_api_log` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `tracking_session_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` char(20) default '',
  `api_request` mediumtext,
  `api_response` mediumtext,
  `api_result` mediumtext,
  `execution_time` float default '-1',
  `date_time` timestamp NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
```

This table is needed for logging.

Any help/pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your XML, you will see the following:

```
<install folder="site">
```

This means that it is looking for:

```
site/sql/install.sql
```

So simply, remove `folder="site"`

Hope this helps

Comment: I've tried this, still 'no-go'. Is it possible at all to run a sql file from a module?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but [this](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_simple_module/Using_the_Database) tutorial suggests it is.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few possible issues.

1. You're not **uninstalling** the module correctly between attempts at installing, so the `install` SQL is not being run.
2. The SQL file is not saved as UTF8 NO BOM (*although this used to cause an error #1064 to be thrown*)
3. The path is not being calculated correctly (*again, this would normally throw an error*)
4. You may have an SQL bug, you say "*it specifically does not execute the create part of the table*", does this mean there is other SQL in the file that you're not showing that could have an error?

#### Suggestions

If you're not seeing any errors I would suggest you make sure that in your `Global Configuration->Server` you have `Error Reporting` set to `Development` and in `Global Configuration->System` you have `Debug System` set to `Yes`.

**Development Error Reporting** — will set the value in the `configuration.php` file to

```
public $error_reporting = 'development';
```

and result in you seeing every error PHP finds.

*NB. sometimes if your errors are bad enough you won't be able to access your site, in this case edit the `configuration.php` and revert to `$error_reporting = 'none'`*

**Debug System** — will set the value in the `configuration.php` file to

```
public $debug = '1';
```

and will add the `Joomla! Debug Console` to the bottom of each page:
[image: Joomla! Debug Console]

*NB.* The section called `Database Queries` will show any SQL logged while the site is in `debug` mode, you can then check through them to see what's happening... i.e. is your SQL being run or not...
[image: Joomla! Debug Console — Database/SQL Queries]

If none of this helps but you get any additional details like errors, add them to your question and I'll try and help further.

Comment: Thanks, thorough answer. By un-installing the module, I delete it from the `#__extensions` table because I don't have a packaged .zip file. I'm using 'Discover Install' to install the module. I will use the debug console and output the errors I might be receiving. But I'm pretty sure the SQL is correct as I tested it in my SQL client beforehand and the table was created w/o error.

Comment: @AnriëtteMyburgh - please say that you have actually tried installing the extension by uploading a zip just to see if it works this way.

Answer (score 0):

I spent many hours on this problem. I found a solution :

- put the sql files in the root of the module
- declare them in the files tag:

  ```
  (filename)install.mysql.utf8.sql(/filenam)
  (filename)uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql(/filename)
  ```

and add the instal/uninstall tags:

```
(install)
    (sql)
        (file charset="utf8" driver="mysql")install.mysql.utf8.sql(/file)
    (/sql)
(/install)

(uninstall)
    (sql)
        (file charset="utf8" driver="mysql")uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql(/file)
    (/sql)
(/uninstall)
```

Not very clean, but I don't want to waste more time searching for the right path